# activesupport causing "No such file to load -- application (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I'm in the process of upgrading a very old app, and all hell is breaking loose. I'm using ruby 2.1.5, rails 4.2.10, and activesupport 4.2.10.

Lots of people on Google with similar issues, but nothing seemed to really be similar enough to my case.

My docker-compose.yml file has the line

`bundle exec rails server`

which returns this error

```
/pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load': No such file to load -- application (LoadError)
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/resource_controller-0.6.6/lib/resource_controller.rb:4:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/resource_controller-0.6.6/lib/resource_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
         from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
         from /pwd/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:45:in `require'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:45:in `block in exec_app_rails'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `loop'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `exec_app_rails'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/bin/rails:9:in `require'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rails:23:in `load'
         from /pwd/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The file `config/application.rb` seems to be missing.

When upgrading very old apps, you might want to generate a new app using your current Rails version 4.2.10, and compare the differences in structure. It might even be easier moving your models, views and controllers into a newly generated app, if much of the structure elsewhere in the project is boilerplate.

Comment: `config/application.rb` exists, and has the proper permissions.

Comment: It seems to have wanted the application ruby gem. Added that, and now it complains about something different :)